# How can I prevent a button from clicking a second time when it already has an Onclick event in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

How can I prevent a button from clicking a second time when it already has an Onclick event in C#...for example is there anyway of checking if it has been clicked again while it has an Onclick event?

Comment: Do you mean disallow clicking or stop executing event handler's code? If the former, then just disable the button in the event handler. If the latter, then create a boolean variable on class level and set its value in the event handler the first time that button is clicked. At the beginning of the event handler check that variable's value to determine whether this event has been executed already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow the button to be clicked only once, you can set `button.enabled = false` in the `onClick()` event.

Or if you just want to know if a button has been clicked before, use a simple flag, the first time it's clicked set it to `true`, then with every subsequent click, check to see if it has already been clicked and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool _processing;
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (_processing) return;
    _processing = true;
    try 
    {
        .... your handler code goes here
    } 
    finally 
    {
        _processing = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7371532/1877909)

you can achieve this in jQuery

> **On the second click, you need to remember when a click has already
>   been made on an element. If it's not going to get more complicated
>   than that, you could use a class for this purpose:**

```
$("selector").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass("clicked-once")) {
        // already been clicked once, hide it
        $this.hide();
    }
    else {
        // first time this is clicked, mark it
        $this.addClass("clicked-once");
    }
});
```